# WPF DataGrid RowHeader Style TargetType

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

[image: DataGrid]

Can I style this "Red" element?

I can set style on DataGridColumnHeader, DataGridRowHeader but I don't know how to set tyle on "red" element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the Top-Left corner of the DataGrid?
It is a button type. You can apply a custom style to it.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you find this is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @A.Klim Please remember to accept answers to close your questions:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work